# MySQL: Join two tables values - one table store user key value and other store defaule value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I am trying to join.

Main table which contain user id with key and it's value

```
id   | user_id | fk_id |   value  
---------------------------
12   |   1     |   1   |   "0"
13   |   1     |   2   |   "1"
15   |   1     |   3   |   "1"
16   |   2     |   1   |   "0"
```

Now I have another table which store default key and it's values:

```
id   | fk_id |   value  
-----------------------
10   |   1   |   "1"
11   |   2   |   "0"
12   |   3   |   "1"
13   |   4   |   "0"
```

And  I want to get values from default table which is not set by user and it's output should be look like as below:

```
user_id | fk_id |   value  
---------------------------
1       |   1   |   "0"
1       |   2   |   "1"
1       |   3   |   "1"
1       |   4   |   "0"
2       |   1   |   "0" 
2       |   2   |   "0"
2       |   3   |   "1"
2       |   4   |   "0"
```

Actually I can do it for single user by using UNION, but I want to achieve for multiple users and if they have not set any key value then need to get it from the default table.

So How to write query to get default values along with user id, if they have not set key's value?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows (all combinations of users and default values) and then a `left join` to bring in the default values.

This looks like:

```
select u.user_id, d.fk_id, coalesce(m.value, d.value) as value
from (select distinct user_id from main) u cross join
     defaults d left join
     main m
     on m.user_id = u.user_id and m.fk_id = d.fk_id;
```

Comment: Using CROSS JOIN and LEFT JOIN does the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, your solution helped me to get solution of my problem, but I have millions of data in main table and it's taking more time to execute.
I have created view for this but still it talking time to execute query.
could you suggest me to optimize this query?

Comment: You can start with using a separate `users` table for `u`.  THen you can add an index on `main(user_id, fk_id, value)`.